# Expand Contained Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is for MongoDB

I have a Document say `Employee` as below:

```
{
  "_id":"e01",
  "name":"Andy",
  "salary":"10000",
  "address":"ad01id"
}
```

That is a simple Employee Document, with address being a foreign key to `Address` Document as below(for this above Employee)

```
{
   "_id": "ad01id",
   "pin":"999",
   "Home":{
           "street":"101",
           "city":"someCity"
          },
   "Country":"someCountry"
}
```

I need a help to write a query which will fetch an `Employee` but will give me an output, which will have `Employee`'s `address` field expanded with its entire document as

```
{
  "_id":"e01",
  "name":"Andy",
  "salary":"10000",
  "address":{
            "pin":"999",
            "Home":{
                    "street":"101",
                    "city":"someCity"
                   },
            "Country":"someCountry"
            }
}
```

I have tried `$lookup` and `$merge` but could not get the desired output - `$merge` hides the keys in the early document if the later document has the same key, which is the case in my real scenario. My actual documents have some keys with the same name. Such as `name` is there in both of my actual Documents.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is needed to "join" the data from both collections and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) or [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) can be used to convert an array being a result of `$lookup` into nested subdocument:

```
db.Employee.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Address",
            localField: "address",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "address"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            address: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$address", 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "address._id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gkCYBlMij1E)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use populate.

```
db.Employee.find(
  {
  },
)
  .populate("address", "pin Home Country")
  .exec(function(err, result) {
     console.log(result)
  });
```